# Generating an ARFF file for Weka from data that isn't CSV

Tags: java, weka, arff

I've been given this problem:

rawarffdata.txt:

```
SampleData

A1    A2    A3    A4    A5    Class

n    n    c    c    c    c

100    10    A31    10    A51    C1

50    15    A32    10    A51    C2

60    30    ?    10    A51    C2

200    8    A31    10    A51    C1

10    20    A32    10    A51    C1

40    5    A33    10    A51    C2
```

The first line of the rawarffdata.txt indicates  the name of the dataset,  the second line indicates the name of  the columns (i.e. attributes) and the third line indicates the types of the attributes. Here n indicates the data type of the attribute is numerical, c indicates the data type of the attribute is categorical, and ? indicates the missing value. The next six rows indicate the records of the rawdata.txt file. The format of the output Sample.ARFF file is shown below:

```
@relation SampleData

@attribute A1 REAL

@attribute A2 REAL

@attribute A3 {'A32', 'A33', 'A31', '?'}

@attribute A4 {'10'}

@attribute A5 {'A51'}

@attribute Class {'C1', 'C2'}

@data

100,10,A31,10,A51,C1,

50,15,A32,10,A51,C2,

60,30,?,10,A51,C2,

200,8,A31,10,A51,C1,

10,20,A32,10,A51,C1,

40,5,A33,10,A51,C2,
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 01**
Convert your text to csv:

https://convertio.co/txt-csv/

**Then open weka**
You can use the ArffViewer:

- Tools -> ArffViewer or Ctrl+A). Then open your CSV file
- Next go to File -> Save as... and select Arff data files

**Method 02**

Convert text file to csv file.

https://support.geekseller.com/knowledgebase/convert-txt-file-csv/

Then convert .csv file to .arff.

**Note:** remove the third row.you can see the data type in weka..no need to put it in csv

Comment: I need to do it in java without any libraries.

Comment: Sounds like an assignment. ;-) Familiarize yourself with [Java's I/O functionality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html). Once you've read the data and [split it into cells](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm), analyze the columns for their type and then write thr ARFF file to disk.